# How to implement AddUsersToRoles method in RoleProvider class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authorization, user-roles

I am developing a simple mvc application where through a select list all users are shown and through another select list all roles are shown. I want to select a user from user dropdown and role from role dropdown. I have done everything but I don't know how to implement the AddUsersToRoles method in Role Provider class and I'm not getting any examples from internet as well. Please provide me an example of AddUsersToRoles method.I tried like this but it gives an error that cannot implicilty covert type string[] to int. Please a solution.

```
  public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        EmployeeDBContext context = new EmployeeDBContext();
        UserRolesMapping userRolesMapping = new UserRolesMapping();
        
        userRolesMapping.RoleID = roleNames;
        userRolesMapping.UserID = usernames;
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of an implementation for this method on the Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.roleprovider.adduserstoroles?view=netframework-4.8#examples).

You might need to change the second half of that example (where it goes to Odbc), as based on your tags you use Entity Framework.

Essentially, you need another database table `UsersInRoles` to link a `User` to a `Role`. Then, create a row in that table for each combination of `usernames` and `roleNames`.

-- Edit:

Based on your example, it looks like you're going in the right direction. However, you're trying to store a `string` into an `int` property.

I don't know your exact model structure, but it should look something like this:

```cs
public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
{
    using (EmployeeDBContext context = new EmployeeDBContext())
    {
        if (context.UsersInRoles == null)
        {
            context.UsersInRoles = new List<UserRolesMapping>();
        }

        foreach (string username in usernames)
        {
            foreach (string roleName in roleNames)
            {
                if(IsUserInRole(username, roleName)) continue;

                UserRolesMapping userRoleMapping = new UserRolesMapping();
                userRoleMapping.Role = roleNames;
                userRoleMapping.User = usernames;

                context.UsersInRoles.Add(userRoleMapping);
            }
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private static bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
{
    using (EmployeeDBContext context = new EmployeeDBContext())
    {
        var userRole = context.UsersInRoles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.User == username && x.Role == roleName);
        return userRole != null;
    }
}
```

Note that you will need to make other code changes to make this work, namely, the `Role` and `User` in this example are `string`s, rather than `int`

Comment: Please see my code i tried like this but it gives an error that cannot implicitly convert type string[] to int. What should i do? please help.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example. You will need to change some code in your project and adapt my suggestion to work with your code.